# androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps

Tags: java, android, kotlin, crash

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.v3(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps(BackStackRecord.java:487)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2401)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2162)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Nobody can help me?
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.v3 is androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.setAnimations

But it's a system function, I can't change it.

I have no idea for fix this error.

Comment: Where exactly is this crash coming from your code? Please share it with us.

Comment: No exactly code for this crash. It's all from Firebase Crashlytics.